# How to select avg(value) per column_name in sql

Tags: sql, group-by, average

I have a table named studios with the columns "earnings" and "country". Each item of that table describes a studio in a country and its earnings.
How can I select the average earnings of the studios for each country?

```
SELECT AVG(earnings) --I want per country
FROM studios
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT country,AVG(earnings) FROM studios GROUP BY country;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that: `"SELECT AVG(earnings) FROM studios GROUP BY country"`
If you have column country_id is for prefer.

You can use and this query `"SELECT AVG(earnings),country FROM studios GROUP BY country"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
SELECT AVG(earnings) , country from studios group by country
```